# CloudQueueMessage Duplicates

Tags: c#, azure

I have created a scheduled task with a master and two listener worker roles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697709.aspx

My listener project has two instances. What prevents two worker roles from getting the same message twice?

Here is my code:

```
    public override void Run()
    {
        // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
        //Trace.TraceInformation("CloudCartConnector.TaskRole entry point called", "Information");
        while (true)
        {
            ExecuteTask();
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
        }
    }


    private void ExecuteTask()
    {
        try
        {
            CloudQueueMessage message = queue.GetMessage();
            if (message != null)
            {
                JMATask task = GetTask(message.AsString);
                queue.DeleteMessage(message);
                PerformTask(task);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Unable to get messages: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a message (or set of messages) from a queue will make the message(s) invisible to other clients of the queue for a period of time ([NextVisibleTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueuemessage.nextvisibletime.aspx)) and as long as you delete the message within that window of time, no other client should ever see it. Therefore it's important to make sure you complete work within the visibility timeout or you could have another worker pick up the same logical message and begin processing it again.

If you know the average amount of time it takes for a worker to process a particular type of message then you can call [the `GetMessage` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee758358.aspx) that takes a `TimeSpan` that specifies exactly how long that visibility timeout should be. The default, for the parameterless overload, is 30 seconds.

Additionally, you can dynamically update the visibility timeout as the processing of a message progresses within a worker role using [`UpdateMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueue.updatemessage.aspx). This way if something might take two hours to process, but there are various steps along the way, you can update visibility timeout as you progress through the steps. This way if processing of a message failed ten minutes into the worker role, it will re-appear and can be picked up sooner.

Comment: And you can update the invisibility timeout any time before the time actually runs out (along with updating the message itself).